# using xlsread in matlab to loop through all .xls files in a folder

Tags: excel, matlab, xlsread

I'm writing a script that needs to loop through all the .xls files in a folder and pull data from specific cells. I think `xlsread` is capable of this, but I keep getting an error that reads:

> Matlab:xlsread:filenotfound

Here is the basic structure of the code:

```
files = dir('C:\folder\folder\folder\*.xls');
channelinfo = 'C:\differentfolder\chanloc.type';
cnt = '.cnt';
condition = 'varriable';


for i = 1:length(files(:,1))
    try

        CNTCrash1WindowStart = xlsread(files(i).name, 'Summary', 'C8');
        CNTCrashWindowEnd = xlsread(files(i).name, 'Summary', 'D8');
        subjectNum = xlsread(files(i).name, 'User Info', 'A2');

        eeglab;
        %eeglab things happen here

    catch ME
        disp(ME)
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you check the existence and content of the `dir` call? I.e. does it find files, and if so, are the file names contained within `files.name`? Could be you're not going to the full path in the `xlsread`, try `tmpname = ['C:\folder\folder\folder\' files(i).name]` and call `xlsread` with that

Comment: i like to add a point to @Adriaan suggestion.. Check whether your file extension is '.xls' or '.xlsx'?

Comment: They are indeed '.xls' extensions; I was hopeful the solution was that simple. I now suspect that the problem is xlsread is calling in the entire filepath instead of the file name, which I don't think it can handle. Could that be it? How could I remove the extra information so xlsread was only grabbing the file name?

Comment: Don't you mean `i = 1:length(files(:,1))`, assuming that you want to got through all of the files? Have you done any debugging? Remove the semicolon on your first line and print out `files(i).name` (this will only be the file name and doesn't include the full path, which you'll need unless the directory in question is your present working directory) inside your loop.

Comment: Yes, Horchler, I did mean to loop through more than one file. Thanks for spotting thing. Also, @Adriaan, your solution worked well! While xlread is a useful tool, it is pretty picky about accepting just file names with no path attached. Splendid.

Comment: @S.Reaves good to know it worked. I'll type it up as answer in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your files are not located in your `pwd` (Present Working Directory). The call to `dir` gives you file names, but not including the full path name. Hence `xlsread` is looking for your .xls files in a location where they are not. Fix this by setting a temporary name where you include the full path and feed that to `xlsread`:

```
folder = 'C:\folder\folder\folder\'; %'//
files = dir([folder, '*.xls']);
channelinfo = 'C:\differentfolder\chanloc.type';
cnt = '.cnt';
condition = 'variable';

for ii = 1:length(files(:,1))
    try
        tempname = fullfile(folder, files(ii).name); %// Thanks to excaza
        CNTCrash1WindowStart = xlsread(tmpname, 'Summary', 'C8');
        CNTCrashWindowEnd = xlsread(tmpname, 'Summary', 'D8');
        subjectNum = xlsread(tmpname, 'User Info', 'A2');

        eeglab;
        %eeglab things happen here

    catch ME
        disp(ME)
    end
end
```

Comment: As a general rule I try to avoid manual concatenation of folders/files and rather favor [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) (e.g. `tempname = fullfile(folder, files(ii).name);`). It ensures the file separators are all present and correct for the filesystem, so it's generally more robust.